# Найти все файлы

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Надо найти все файлы с любым расширением, почему, если в названии больше двух слов, то не ищет? Папки не надо

```
$str = 'Новый текстовый документ.txt';
echo preg_match('#[a-z0-9A-ZА-Яа-я\s]+\.[a-z]+#', $str);
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php

Comment: я же все расширения не буду перечислить

Comment: ..............`*.*` ?

Comment: `$temp_files = glob(__dir__.'/*'); foreach($temp_files as $file) {.............}`

Comment: мне папки не нужны

Comment: я же написал `*.*`... совместить не судьба `$temp_files = glob(__dir__.'/*'); 
foreach($temp_files as $file) {
echo $file.'<br/>';
}`?

Answer (score 1):

> *почему, если в названии больше двух слов, то не ищет?*

Потому что надо использовать глобальный поиск **preg_match_all()**

```
$str = 'Новый текстовый документ.txt';
preg_match_all('#[a-zа-яё0-9\s]+\.[a-z]+$#iu', $str, $arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал так:

```
$dir = 'some_directory';
$files = scandir($dir);
$result = array();

foreach($files as $file) {
    if(is_file($file)) {
        array_push($result, $file);
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```